# On demand water heater flow loss

Tags: water, heater

I removed a traditional water heater with 1" fittings and 3/4" pex to and from it with a on demand heater that has 1/2" fittings.

So I currently have 3/4" pex to the heater with 1/2" fittings.  I have noticed a significant decrease in flow to the shower.  Is there an easy way to resolve this?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Get a different water heater with larger fittings.